# TFDUpdateSQL or TFDQuery gets error after sql execute with params ftWideString

Tags: delphi, dataset, advantage-database-server, firedac

When I Execute the sql I get an error:

[image]

Database: Advantage (ADS)

initialization of the update sql:

```
procedure TWarehouseLocationAgent.InitUpdateSQL;
var
  oCmd: TFDCustomCommand;
begin
  inherited;
  oCmd := self.UpdateSQL.Commands[arUpdate];
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('UPDATE ARTIKELMAGAZIJN SET LOCATIE= :ALOCATION');
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('  WHERE ARTIKELNUMMER= :APARTID');
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('   AND MAGAZIJNNUMMER= :AWAREHOUSEID');

end;
```

Update data procedure:

```
procedure TWarehouseLocationAgent.Update(AWarehouseLocation: TWarehouseLocation);
var
  oCmd: TFDCustomCommand;
begin
  oCmd:= self.UpdateSQL.Commands[arUpdate];
  oCmd.ParamByName('ALOCATION').AsString := AWarehouseLocation.Location;
  oCmd.ParamByName('APARTID').AsInteger := AWarehouseLocation.PartID;
  oCmd.ParamByName('AWAREHOUSEID').AsInteger := AWarehouseLocation.WarehouseID;

  oCmd.Execute;  //--> get error
  if oCmd.RowsAffected <> 1 then
    raise ECFException.Create('Warehouselocation not found');
end;
```

What I found is that param 'ALOCATION' have a datatype of ftwidestring.
so I've change the procedure InitUpdateSQL with params.
When I use the ftwidestring then I get the error and if I use a ftstring the execute runs.

Field 'LOCATIE' in database is char(30).

Strange that the Dataset set a ftWidestring if I must use the ftString.

Why can't I use the ftWideString?

```
procedure TWarehouseLocationAgent.InitUpdateSQL;
var
  oCmd: TFDCustomCommand;
  oParam: TFDParam;
begin
  inherited;
  oCmd := self.UpdateSQL.Commands[arUpdate];
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('UPDATE ARTIKELMAGAZIJN SET LOCATIE= :ALOCATION');
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('  WHERE ARTIKELNUMMER= :APARTID');
  oCmd.CommandText.Add('   AND MAGAZIJNNUMMER= :AWAREHOUSEID');

  oCmd.Params.Clear;
  oParam:= oCmd.Params.Add;
  oParam.Name:='ALOCATION';
  //oParam.DataType := ftWideString;  <-- error with ftWideString
  oParam.DataType := ftString; // no error, why?

  oParam:= oCmd.Params.Add;
  oParam.Name:='APARTID';
  oParam.DataType := ftInteger;

  oParam:= oCmd.Params.Add;
  oParam.Name:='AWAREHOUSEID';
  oParam.DataType := ftInteger;
end;
```

Comment: When you say "What I found is that param 'ALOCATION' have a datatype of ftwidestring", how have you found that out?  Is that what FireDAC sets as the Param type in the IDE?

Comment: @MartynA: Yes was set by FireDac. Found by debugging step by step.